# Running script file through subprocess

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm attempting to run a Linux script through Python's subprocess module. Below is the subprocess command:

```
result = subprocess.run(['/dir/scripts/0_texts.sh'], shell=True)
print(result)
```

Here is the `0_texts.sh` script file:

```
cd /dir/TXTs

pylanguagetool text_0.txt > comments_0.txt
```

The subprocess command executes the script file, writing a new `comments_0.txt` in the correct directory. However, there's an error in the execution. The `comments_0.txt` contains an error of "input file is required", and the subprocess result returns `returncode=2`. When I run the `pylanguagetool text_0.txt > comments_0.txt` directly in the terminal the command executes properly, with the `comments_0.txt` written with the proper input file of `text_0.txt`.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: it sounds like if you ran `/dir/scripts/0_texts.sh` in the terminal it would also fail? are you sure the paths (eg `cd /dir/TXTs`) are correct?

Comment: I ran the 0_texts.sh in terminal, and it runs correctly, writing the new file in the correct directory with the right input file. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

There is some ambiguity here in that it's not obvious which shell is run each time `0_texts.sh` is invoked, and whether it has the values you expect of environment variables like `PATH`, which could result in a different copy of `pylanguagetool` running from when you call it at the command line.

First I'd suggest removing the `shell=True` option in `subprocess.run`, which is only involving another, potentially different shell here. Next I would change `subprocess.run(['/dir/scripts/0_texts.sh'])` to `subprocess.run(['bash', '/dir/scripts/0_texts.sh'])` (or whichever shell you wanted to run, probably `bash` or `dash`) to remove that source of ambiguity. Finally, you can try using `type pylanguagetool` in the script, invoking `pylanguagetool` with its full path, or calling `bash /dir/scripts/0_texts.sh` from your terminal to debug the situation further.

A bigger-picture issue is, pyLanguageTool is a Python library, so you're almost certainly going to be better off calling its functions from your original Python script directly instead of using a shell script as an intermediary.